# man gcc not working

Tags: linux, gcc, man

I was trying to read about how to make gcc compile C code to plain assembly for a bootloader, but when I tried to read the man pages there were none!

```
$ man gcc
No manual entry for gcc
See 'man 7 undocumented' for help when manual pages are not available.
$
```

I tried to remove and then reinstall it, but without luck. I'm on debian 6.0.3 and gcc 4.4.5

Thanks

Comment: If you have to read it online or install documentation with another package, you should probably type "gcc --version" to make sure you're looking at documentation for the right version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation isn't in the "gcc" package, it's in a separate package called "gcc-doc".

Comment: This doesn't work for me, as I get the following:

`Package gcc-doc is not available, but is referred to by another package.`
`This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or`
`is only available from another source`

`E: Package 'gcc-doc' has no installation candidate`

Answer (score 1):

Or just use

http://linux.die.net/man/1/gcc